# What response should I return when returning an excel document in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I use openpyxl create a workbook, and return a Response like this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')  
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.xlsx"'
return response
```

but frontend coder said he accept gibberish, you should return a bytearray like 0101010101,he can analysis and download
Now I return a response like this, he use node.js not vue download through a complex process
I am confused, what should I do?

Comment: Node.js is not a frontend technology and since you didn't included a clear description of the other side, I removed the tags and reference.

Answer (score 0):

To make a direct link to file try to use `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` content type.

I recomend you to use [django-excel](http://docs.pyexcel.org/en/latest/) to work with excel. It's pretty easy to use and you could integrate different formats later.

There're alot of [examples](https://github.com/pyexcel-webwares/django-excel/blob/4b8a71f48a20d7f9f4abc4d12130f5a2a14696fc/polls/views.py) of downloading views. Check the methods starts with `make_response_from_`. I guess you could use some of them to build a file and return it as response.